# Story: sharing a ventilator, slowing heart rate

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a story where there are 3 or 4 main characters in a post-apocalyptic or maybe off-Earth situation. Something is wrong with the air, and so the characters need to share a makeshift ventilator.

There's a plot point involving a chemical, a drug, which slows down one's heart rate so they require less oxygen.

I believe the story ends in tragedy, maybe the death of one of the main characters.

---

I'm looking for a piece of fiction that may or may not exist. Let me explain. I have had a recurring dream for years that has a few important plot points as described above. For that reason, I think I may be combining existing plot elements from books or movies I've consumed and mashing them together in my subconscious... They seem reasonable when taken as a whole, though.

Comment: I've removed some of the off topic chatter, try and keep your posts as clean as possible! This is a good description though! Can you remember when you would have read/seen this? Would it have been new at the time? Can you remember any of the plot of this? If you have anything else to add please [edit] those details into your question. Welcome to SFF! You may also want to take the [tour] to learn a bit about the site.

Comment: Was one of the protagonists with a mutation that allowed them to hibernate? I remember a story ( I thought that it was part of Stross's  "Accelerando", but I might be confusing this with another story), where one protagonist has to make sure the "hibernating" protagonist has at least one last oxygen tank.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if some of this comes from Arthur C Clarke's *[A Fall Of Moondust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fall_of_Moondust)*.

It's not post-apocalyptic, but it is on the Moon so off-Earth. There is a point where the *Selene*'s air is starting to get bad from everyone breathing, so all but two of the passengers are tranquilised to use less oxygen; the two that are left share an oxygen cylinder. No tragic ending though.